# What do sub curly brackets indicate?

Tags: functions, notation

What do the curly brackets mean in this context?

$$f(x) = 2 \cdot x \cdot 1_{x>0}$$

Is this a condition?

Comment: More context would be helpful here - without a bit more information it's hard to discern what's going on.  One good possibility is that the characteristic function - that is, the function that takes the value $1$ at arguments in the set $A$ and $0$ at arguments not in the set $A$, is often written as $\mathbf{1}_A$.  Here, that would mean the function $g(x)$ defined as $g(x) = 1, x\gt 0; g(x) = 0, x\leq 0 $.

Comment: As mentioned in the popup that is supposed to appear when you tagged this [tag:notation], you are supposed to have included where you saw this notation. We're answerers, not mind-readers.

Comment: @Soo : Since your title mentions "sub curly brackets", I wonder if you meant $2\cdot x\cdot1_{\{x>0\}}$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The $\Bbb 1_{x>0}$ is the indicator function $^1$ that indicates if $x$ is greater than $0$ or not.
$$1_{x>0}=\begin{cases} 1, ~~x>0\\0, ~~x \le 0\end{cases}$$

This makes your function into,

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}2x,~~x>0\\0, ~~x \le0 \end{cases}$$

**Footnotes:**

$^1$(also called the Characteristic function, denoted by $\chi_A$ is the function that takes $1$ when $x \in A$ and $0$ otherwise.)

Comment: It's a convenient function, though I personally prefer Iverson brackets myself...

Comment: I have never heard of Iverson Brackets until you mention it to me. @J.M. Thank You. Wikipedia had to rescue me!

Comment: What a weird notational convention; I never saw this before. I suppose one could also write $0_{x\leq0}$ instead of $1_{x>0}$ :-). Long live Iverson!

Comment: Dear Professor @MarcvanLeeuwen, This is weird but, I think you'd agree not as weirder as [Iverson Brackets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) :)
On a lighter note, I happen to have heard of a Saint from Poitiers, St. Montfort.

Comment: Macaulay brackets anybody?